# Why is there a wifi network called directzp-(computer-name)-msOV

Tags: wireless-networking

Why is there a wifi network called directzp-(computer-name)-msOV, when I was trying to connect to wifi with my VR headset, that showed up, but my wifi network didn't show up and I couldn't connect. Any Help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could be related to Wi-Fi Direct.